# Сравнение массива на полное соответствие

Tags: swift

У меня есть два массива:

```html
var mass1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var mass2 = ["9", "3", "2", "1", "4"]

if mass1 != mass2 {
}
```

Мне необходимо сравнить два массива на полное несоответствие, чтобы все элементы первого массива != всем элементам второго массива.
Я так полагаю это сделать через двойной цикл, в котором сравнивать все элементы, как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой способ преобразовать массив в `Set` и сравнить их на различия.

```
func isEqualArray(_ array1: [Int], with array2: [Int]) -> Bool {
      return Set(array1).symmetricDifference(array2).count == 0 : true ? false    
}
```

Можно использовать `intersection` для поиска пересечений `Set`:

```
func isEqualArray(_ array1: [Int], with array2: [Int]) -> Bool {
      return Set(array1).intersection(array2).count == 0 : false ? true    
}
```

Соответственно если пересечений нету, значит наборы различны.